# Are the creators and Lockdown related to Cybertron?

Tags: transformers, transformers-age-of-extinction, transformers-live-action-series

Is Cybertron the only Transformers planet the creators had seeded? 
If yes, does that mean Lockdown is a Cybertronian? Or is he an independent custom rendition of the Creators?

Comment: Is there two different questions here?

Comment: I suppose not, as Lockdown works for the creators, hence I'm curious about their origins.

Answer (score 1):

Within *Age of Extinction* itself, there is no direct evidence that Cybertron was seeded.

There is, however, evidence of other planets being seeded - including Earth.

> *Cade*: Wait. The Seed?
>
> *Tessa*: Those nasty soldiers that were chasing us. I saw them board the ship and they took something that they called the seed.
>
> *Hound*: Listen. Sixty million years ago, give or take an eon...
>
> *Optimus*: Thousands of planets were cyber-formed with Seeds. They turned your organic life into our elemental metals. Our creators destroyed your world to make us.

Whether or not Lockdown is a Cybertronian is left unspecified within the movie, but he has one quote that makes it sound as though he at least pre-dates the two factions.

> *Lockdown*: Autobots, Decepticons, like little children: always fighting, making a mess out of the universe. Then I've got to clean it up.